# jquery-mobile 1.4.5 popup listview click not working on large content

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, popup

I have a jquery-mobile page which contains a popup. The popup gets filled with dynamic content, displayed as a listview. Each li element has a click listener attached. Works for far, but for long listviews, all li items which were not visible when the popup opened seem to lose their click listener. This happens on mobile browsers: IOS Safari, Android stock browser, Chrome on Android. New Firefox works, also Desktop browsers (edit: not Chrome on OSX). No tablets to test. Any ideas? [Test page here](http://aporee.org/test/popup.html)

Comment: show the community what you've tried

Comment: I've provided a link to a test page, that's what I've tried, and there I'm stuck. Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy solution for your problem.

Just use iScrollView plugin inside your popup. This way you can limit popup dimensions and still retain long list view inside a popup.

Tutorial && working example: http://www.gajotres.net/using-iscroll-with-jquery-mobile/2/

#### HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Index page</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop">Basic Popup</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
            <div class="header" data-role="header">
                <h1>Products</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="content" data-role="content" data-iscroll>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>                
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>                
                </ul>                
            </div>
            <div class="footer" data-role="footer">
                <a class="close" href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </div>

    <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>    
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.ui-content {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.ui-listview {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

div.iscroll-scroller {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.ui-popup .ui-content {
    height: 150px !important;
}
```

If you have a comment leave it below and if you like this example don't forget to accept it.

Comment: thanks, but for some reason the example on your page doesn't work fo me, when I try to scroll it moves the whole content. An example on the iscroll page at github works, so I'll give it a try. I'll be back... ;)